# Four layer architecture and classification of storage class

Tags: c#, database, oop, architecture, software-design

I'm studying computer science and for practice reasons I want to split my program / classes into four layers GUI -> Controller -> Model -> Database, however I only want to access the Database as rarely as possible (maybe even just once) which means I will load information into a class that will contain a collection of objects from the database. In other words the class will act as a storage.

My question is rather simple really, would I classify this storage class as a Model-layer class or a Database-layer class? The relevance being whether I want to allow my controller to access said class or not.

Comment: who cares? Pick a set of abstractions that make your code the best and go with it. Typically what you are describing is a 3 tier architecture by the way, the database isn't a layer. The "storage" class is a repository (part of the model)

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. For some reason I was convinced that the database was a layer by itself. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I mean; it is a "layer" it just exists outside your application and so doesn't fall within your class-based architectural concerns

Answer (score 0):

On Enterprise levels, they can have many layers, but typical is UI, Service, Business Login, and Data access, but some combine them. I do microservices so it's much more complex. Some put business logic in service layer, some dont. Some dont have Data access layer.  Simplicity is key to success of solution. Depends on what you need and who for.